# Finding Any Remote Connections

Tags: 14.04, remote-access, remote

I want to find out if there are any current / inactive remote connections setup on my Ubuntu desktop.

Is there a command, script, or similar that will allow me to see if there any remote access or connections to my desktop?

Answer (score 2):

I always use `netstat -putan` for that. It's easy to remember.

- `-p`: Show the PID and name of the program to which each socket belongs.
- `-u`: Show udp sockets
- `-t`: Show tcp sockets
- `-a`: Show both listening and non-listening sockets.
- `-n`: Show numerical addresses instead of trying to determine symbolic host, port or user names.

Output looks like this:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2307/sshd
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
netstat -a
```

tcpdump is another good command.  Wireshark is free packet sniffer software that will analyze your network traffic.  That's really the best way to dig deep into what's going on with your traffic.

Comment: When I do netstat -a it fills the terminal with the results and I am not able to scroll up all the way. Is there a command to display the results "LESS" then allow me to scroll down myself.

Comment: Use the "more" output option: `netstat -a | more` This will display one page at-a-time.  Hit Enter or Space to scroll down with keyboard only.